# How to make a script that execute a command when two parameters are similar for 5 minutes?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sh

I'm using cURL to get some data from a website, so how to do to execute a command if two parameters from this website is the same for 5 minutes?

```
#!/bin/bash

TIME= "300s"

abc=`$CURL ***
abcd=`$CURL *** 

echo $abc
echo $abcd 

if [ [ [ "$abc" -eq "eee" || "$abc" -eq "rrr" ] || [ "$abcd" -eq "eee" || "$abcd" -eq "rrr" ] ] -ge [ "$TIME" ] ] 
then
  echo "Critical hosts: "$abc
  echo "Critical service: "$abcd
fi
```

So if `$abc` and `$abcd` are `== "eee"` or `== "rrr"` for 5 minutes then do the command.

Comment: The script is mostly broken; it does not execute. Please fix it. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Comment: Simple: 1/ Describe in natural language what you want. Ensure it is exhaustive and non redundant. 2/ use pseudo code to describe how you want to do it, first at high level and then at lower level until each line looks simple to translate in shell script. And only then 3/ write and test the script.  You have skipped the 2 first steps, so I will not waste time debugging a script that has no evident structure for meeting non detailed requirements.

Comment: How often do they change? If they can change every second and you only check them once a minute for 5 minutes, you could easily believe they had remained the same when, in fact, they had differed wildly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below the skeleton to your script. You will have to implement `my_curl_function` yourself, but I suggest to call the curl function once and parse the data for both `SERVER` and `SERVICE`. Calling it once for each variable brings a lot of overhead, which causes the loop not to be exactly 5 minutes (which it isn't already). If you really, really, really want it to be exactly 5 minutes, use Python ;-)

The script validates every second whether the content of `SERVER` or `SERVICE` is changed. If either one of them are different than what's expected, the loop will break and the script echoes `"Data is changed"`. It will echo `"Data remains unchanged"` otherwise.

```
#! /bin/bash

function my_curl_function {
    echo "Implement me!"
}

MYTIME=300

SERVER_EXPECTED=$(my_curl_function)
SERVICE_EXPECTED=$(my_curl_function)
SERVER=""
SERVICE=""

CHANGED=0

for ((x=0; x<MYTIME;x++)); do

    SERVER=$(my_curl_function)
    SERVICE=$(my_curl_function)

    if [ "${SERVER_EXPECTED}" != "${SERVER}" ] || [ "${SERVICE_EXPECTED}" != "${SERVICE}" ]; then
        CHANGED=1
        break
    fi
    echo -ne "\rSeconds waiting: $x"
    sleep 1
done
echo

if [ ${CHANGED} -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Data is changed"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Data remains unchanged"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You could fix an strictly 5 minutes timing in Bash, but you will have time the curl command and parsing the data. If it took N minutes, you will have to add `((x = x + N))` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta The script here isn't the full one,I just put here the minimum to understand what I wanted to do